# Convert sql date to string in Java8

Tags: java-8

I am new to Java8

If I want to convert sqldate to string then what should I use?

```
1) Simpledateformat (which is easier) or
2) Convert the sql date to LocalDate and then use DateTimeFormatter
```

I want to know is it good practice to use Simpledateformat in Java8 when we have DateTimeFormatter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I would go with the second way**, because the newer format engine `DateTimeFormatter` is **immutable** in contrast to `SimpleDateFormat` and also offers a more modern API in general. It is even more performant than the old stuff, especially in multi-threading-environment (although there are still quicker libraries outside according to my observations).

It is also very easy to convert `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate` thanks to a built-in [conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) method.

**In addition:** Since your SQL-date represents a plain calendar date, the type `LocalDate` is semantically a much better match than the type `java.util.Date` (used by `SimpleDateFormat`) because latter one represents a global instant which is quite different from a calendar date. So going the second way you don't need to bother with any time component which makes the problem/task easier to understand regarding your input.